# WordPress installation on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wordpress

I am new in Ubuntu. Recently I am using Ubuntu 12.10. When I used window xp I used WordPress in XAMPP. The installation press of WordPress in windows xp on XAMPP is very simple, only copy the downloaded WordPress file on 'htdocs' folder and change some come on 'wpconfig.php', then ready to use. Now in Ubuntu 12.10, I using LAMPP, do the same process as windows xp but don't works.

Any suggestion ...

Comment: Why not install it from repositories `apt-get install wordpress`? Then read the instructions in /usr/share/doc/wordpress

Comment: same goes for apache2, mysql-server and php5

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have LAMP stack installed to set up Wordpress.

1) **Install Apache HTTP Server**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

2) Check if its working by going to `http://localhost/`

3) **Install PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

4) In order for PHP to work with Apache you need to restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

5) **Install MySQL**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

6) Optional **Install phpMyAdmin** (Recommended : Make's Life Easier)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

7) **To add phpMyAdmin to Apache web server you need to edit apache2.conf file**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

8) **Add this to the last line of apache2.conf file**

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

9) **Then you need to reconfigure your phpMyAdmin package**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

10) Restart Apache and everything should work

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Note: When you reconfigure phpMyAdmin it might ask about which socket you're going to use select Unix Socket.

**The htdocs directory in Ubuntu is `/var/www`**